# Should i use transform:translateY for vertical centering?

Tags: css, transform, center

Can i use

```
top:50%
transform:translateY(-50%)
```

or should i use it if all other methods dont work?

Comment: This is an opinion based question and so **off-topic** for Stack Overflow. Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty legitimate method of vertical centering. The only problem is the sometimes because of pixel fractions rendering, the result is a bit blurred.
You can fix that if you add `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the parent container.